# Static does not loads static files in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is my directory structure

```
app_web
    _init_.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
upload_app
    migrations/
    static/
       js/
         alert.js 
    templates/
       upload.html
    _init_.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

In `settings.py` , my

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

and in my upload.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/alert.js" %}"></script>
```

It does not works and throws 404 error everytime. I even tried `load static` but it still cannot load anything from static folder and throws 404 error.

I am using Windows 10 machine and Django==1.9

Comment: Sorry, `{% load static from staticfiles %}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It throws error `'staticfiles' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'static'`

Comment: Although `django.contrib.staticfiles` is present inside settings.py

Comment: Did you add STATICFILES_DIRS in your settings?

Comment: Fixed it, can you look at my answer and provide suggestion based on it @leelum1

Comment: @leelum1 : Yes, STATICFILES_DIRS woorks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was to create a `static` directory outside the `upload_app` folder. The reason is that in the `settings.py` the `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` . That means one directory above is the base directory, so it will start searching `static/` from that directory. But it will never find it as I placed inside `upload_app/static` .

Also, I need to work on putting `templates` outside the app `upload_app` as it's not generally best practice to keep templates inside the app.

looking for other suggestions in structure